Can I pass multiple parameters through a rewrite rule on a IIS web.config file?
Whenever I try to use this rule:
<rule name="Rewrite to test.php without parameters" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^pdf/pdf/([^/]+)/(\d+)$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="test.php?tipodoc={R:1}&ndoc={R:2}" />
</rule>

I get an error 500.
I found out that it only fired if I tried passing two parameters instead of one. Either tipodoc or ndoc by themselves work.

I found it myself. The & had to be:
&amp;

for the XML parser
